# Removing dynamically created li containing mulitple sources from ul

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <ul>
        <li class="clearfix"><span class="pull-left">One leg</span><a href="#" class="ae__add-cart pull-right"><img src="images/plus-icon.png" alt="" /><span>Add to Cart</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Two Leg</span><a href="#" class="ae__add-cart pull-right"><img src="images/plus-icon.png" alt=""><span>Add to Cart</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Full</span><a href="#" class="ae__add-cart pull-right"><img src="images/plus-icon.png" alt=""><span>Add to Cart</span></a></li>
        <li class="clearfix"><span class="pull-left">Half</span><a href="#" class="ae__add-cart pull-right"><img src="images/plus-icon.png" alt=""><span>Add to Cart</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul id="ae__orders__content">
</ul>



$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".clearfix").click(function () {
        var temp = $(this).text();
        var updatedString = temp.replace("Add to Cart", "");

        $("#ae__orders__content").append("<li id=\"" + updatedString + "\" class=\"clearfix\"><span class=\"pull-left\">");
        $("#ae__orders__content").append("<b>" + updatedString + "</b></span><a href=\"#\" class=\"ae__remove-cart pull-right\"><img src=\"images/sm-icon.png\" alt=\"\">Remove from Cart</a></li>");
    });
});
```

I am trying to dynamically add li when someone clicks Add to Cart. It goes to to cart in the ul with id "ae__orders__content". Till this part everything is working fine. but i want to remove li that is added dynamically when remove from cart is clicked. I have tried almost everything and found the solution given below. It removes all the items from UL instead the only LI that is clicked.

```
$("#ae__orders__content").click(function () {
    //$(this).children().focus().remove();
    alert("remove");
    //$('li', ul).last().remove();
    $(this).children().remove();

    return false;

});
```

[Add to cart is working fine. I want to remove li when remove from cart is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdb12.jpg)

Comment: `$(this).remove();`

Comment: @James . Thanks for the prompt reply but I have tried this as well. It is removing all the li's from ul instead of the clicked one.

Comment: Oh right you are, the clicked item is the ul, so it will remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the `<a>` that gets appended to be the click target for removing the li, so:

```
$(".ae__orders__content").on("click", "a.ae__remove-cart", function () {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: $(this).parent().remove(); is removing the UL. and then i tried $(this).remove(); which is only removing the anchor tag part only. its not removing the li tag

Comment: Weird!  Because the `li` is clearly the parent of the `a`.  Check that your html layout is correct after doing a couple of appends by using browser dev tools.

Comment: Thanks alot. There was the issue with the html layout. It's working now thanks once again.